# Search Text Does not Have Response in Predicate SwiftUI

Tags: search, swiftui, nspredicate

searchText changes do not change predicate input, hence whatever I type inside the search bar I always get all of the reminders inside core data.

I want my list to change according to text typed inside the search bar.

Here is my SearchView

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest var reminder: FetchedResults<CDReminder>
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    init(searchText: State<String>) {
        self._searchText = searchText
        var predicate : NSPredicate?
        if !self._searchText.wrappedValue.isEmpty{
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", self._searchText.wrappedValue)
        }
        self._reminder = FetchRequest(
            entity: CDReminder.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [],
            predicate: predicate
        )
    }
    var body: some View {
         VStack {
       SearchBar(text: searchText)
       List {
        ForEach(self._reminder.wrappedValue.filter({
            self.searchText.isEmpty ? true :
         $0.notes!.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchText)
            }), id: \.self){ reminder in
            DatedReminderCell(reminder: reminder, isSelected: false, 
           onComplete: {})
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

And my searchBar

```
    struct SearchBar: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State private var isEditing = false
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                TextField("Search", text: $text)
                    .overlay(
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            if isEditing {
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.text = ""
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.isEditing = true
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: SearchView and SearchBar are not binded with “searchText" property. So, search SearchView doesn’t know anything about what you are typing in SearchBar. Also, if you bind them you still need to make a new fetch request in "SearchView" to get updated results, init() will not be invoked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another View called FilteredList. In this View, I fetched all the reminders and then filtered them with a predicate.

```
 import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FilteredList: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<CDReminder>
    var reminders: FetchedResults<CDReminder> {fetchRequest.wrappedValue}
    var body: some View {
        List(fetchRequest.wrappedValue , id: \.self) { reminder in
            DatedReminderCell(reminder: reminder, isSelected: false, onComplete: {})
        }
    }
    
    init(filter: String) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<CDReminder>(
            entity: CDReminder.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", filter.lowercased())
        )
    }
}
```

Then, I updated my SearchView with FilteredList instead of using List { ForEach statement. so the body of my SearchView is now like this.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        SearchBar(text: $searchText)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        FilteredList(filter: searchText)
    }
}
```

So right now, when I enter text inside the search bar I see related reminders simultaneously.